# rsync option problem

Tags: debian, rsync

I use rsync for home backup.

```
cat /usr/local/bin/backup-home-skript 
#!/bin/bash

rsync  --delete -aAXERogvrptchx  --ignore-existing --log-file=/home/alex/.rsync.log --exclude=/home/alex/iso-images /home/alex/ /media/debianhome/alex && /usr/bin/aplay -q /home/alex/Musik/Wave/game-over.wav

exit 0
```

What I wish that the folders and files under /home/alex will be synchronized to /media/debianhome/alex. But rsync generate under /media/debianhome/alex the folder home and wrote the backup in this folder.

How can I avoid this. I tried  `rsync  --delete -aAXERogvrptchx  --ignore-existing --log-file=/home/alex/.rsync.log --exclude=/home/alex/iso-images /home/alex/* /media/debianhome/alex` but this seems not the right way.

Comment: Drop the `-R` (relative path names). See the manual. Also, try trimming down `-aAXERogvrptchx`. Half of those options are probably not needed.

Comment: Okay, message to Bahamut -R  != -r in rsync.

Comment: Also, `-r` is implied by `-a`, as are some of the others.

Comment: it seems not all data are copied. `find /home/alex/ -user alex | wc -l
123748` vs `find /media/debianhome/alex/ -user alex | wc -l
123478` Before I start the skript again I cleared the Partition.